# pandas DataFrame assign with format

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use assign to create a new column in a pandas DataFrame. I need to use something like str.format to have the new column be pieces of existing columns. For instance...

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 3))
```

gives me...

```
              0         1         2
    0 -0.738703 -1.027115  1.129253
    1  0.674314  0.525223 -0.371896
    2  1.021304  0.169181 -0.884293
```

an assign for a totally new column works

```
# works
print(df.assign(c = "a"))

              0         1         2  c
    0 -0.738703 -1.027115  1.129253  a
    1  0.674314  0.525223 -0.371896  a
    2  1.021304  0.169181 -0.884293  a
```

But, if I want to use an existing column into a new column it seems like pandas is adding the whole existing frame into the new column.

```
# doesn't work
print(df.assign(c = "a{}b".format(df[0])))

              0         1         2  \
    0 -0.738703 -1.027115  1.129253   
    1  0.674314  0.525223 -0.371896   
    2  1.021304  0.169181 -0.884293   

                                                       c  
    0  a0   -0.738703\n1    0.674314\n2    1.021304\n...  
    1  a0   -0.738703\n1    0.674314\n2    1.021304\n...  
    2  a0   -0.738703\n1    0.674314\n2    1.021304\n...
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [131]: df.assign(c="a"+df[0].astype(str)+"b")
Out[131]: 
          0         1         2                  c
0  0.833556 -0.106183 -0.910005   a0.833556419295b
1 -1.487825  1.173338  1.650466   a-1.48782514804b
2 -0.836795 -1.192674 -0.212900  a-0.836795026809b
```

---

`'a{}b'.format(df[0])` is a `str`.  `"a"+df[0].astype(str)+"b"` is a Series.

```
In [142]: type(df[0].astype(str))
Out[142]: pandas.core.series.Series

In [143]: type('{}'.format(df[0]))
Out[143]: str
```

When you assign a single string to the column `c`, that string is repeated for every row in `df`.
Thus, `df.assign(c = "a{}b".format(df[0]))` assigns the string `'a{}b'.format(df[0])`
to each row of `df`:

```
In [138]: 'a{}b'.format(df[0]) 
Out[138]: 'a0    0.833556\n1   -1.487825\n2   -0.836795\nName: 0, dtype: float64b'
```

It is really no different than what happened with `df.assign(c = "a")`.

In contrast, when you assign a Series to the column `c`, then the index of the Series is aligned with the index of `df` and the corresponding values are assigned to `df['c']`.

---

Under the hood, the `Series.__add__` method is defined in such a way so that addition of the Series containing strings with a string results in a new Series with the string concatenated with the values in the Series:

```
In [149]: "a"+df[0].astype(str)
Out[149]: 
0     a0.833556419295
1     a-1.48782514804
2    a-0.836795026809
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

(The `astype` method was called to convert the floats in `df[0]` into strings.)

Comment: Cool that there are two ways to accomplish the answer. For edification, why doesn't format work?

Answer (score 0):

```
df['c'] = "a" + df[0].astype(str) + 'b'
df


       0    1   2   c
0   -1.134154   -0.367397   0.906239    a-1.13415403091b
1   0.551997    -0.160217   -0.869291   a0.551996920472b
2   0.490102    -1.151301   0.541888    a0.490101854737b
```